# How to know which app has virus on my Android?

Tags: android

I just got a push notification to download some "ICQ client" from maeu.net, but don't know an easy way to get the package name of the faulty app that received it, how do i do that not programmatically? The pid is in the logs:

```
I/ActivityManager( 2695): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW cat=[android.intent.category.BROWSABLE] dat=http://maeu.net/jimm/3220/jimm.apk cmp=com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity } from pid 6434
```

I think FLV Player was written on the notification but after clicking on it, I can't find it again to verify that. I downloaded Terminal Emulator but `ps` can't see that process any more.

Comment: http://contagiominidump.blogspot.com/2011/09/jimm-icq-sms-rojan-pushed-by-malicious.html

Comment: Kind of sounds like an AirPush, maybe try this? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.brosmike.airpushdetector&hl=en

Not really a virus, but rather just a really scummy kind of advertising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently I saw something like this as well and was immediately scared. Some apps have certain "Ads" that run inside apps and can send you notifications or create shortcuts.

Because of this I made sure I had a good "anti-virus", such as:

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lookout
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.symantec.mobilesecurity
```

I tend to use both apps because I am paranoid about security when it comes to online data security :)

Also, you will need apps that scan and search for other apps with "Ads", such as:

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.denper.addonsdetector
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.brosmike.airpushdetector
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lookout.addetector
```

These apps will quickly find the applications on your phone that can do "certain" things with "Ads" such as special permissions.

Once you find the apps that maybe causing the problem, simply uninstall them!

Please let me know if this helps!